# Play embed YouTube without pressing the red button

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube-api, uigesturerecognizer, youtube-iframe-api

I am using webview to play the embed YouTube. Is there the way to play video without pressing the red button? Example: If I click a button outside the webview, the video will automatically play without pressing the red button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a way to dynamically adjust the video player controls in a `UIWebView`.  What you can do is load the video and have it autoplay when your `UIButton` is pressed:

Append `autoplay=1` to your URL (ex: `https://www.youtube.com/embed/FQfJQZegamE?autoplay=1`).

Then set `mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` to NO on your `UIWebView`.

```
// in your IBAction or button selector
UIWebView *webView = [UIWebView ...];
// load video URL into your webview
[webView setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks JAL. Can I call javascript in this case? I tried to use this code:  [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"ytplayer.playVideo()"];
However, it still does not work

Comment: I'm not sure if calling iFrame methods like that will work.  Like I've said previously, the only sanctioned way to play YouTube videos in an ios app is the [youtube-ios-player-helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper) class from YouTube.